# How to minimise pointers while minimising time

Tags: c, performance, pointers

In an embedded application, I need to read a binary file into the limited memory,
then parse it in minimum time.

The whole file can be read and memory allocated:

```
char **array = malloc(sizeof(char *) * row);
for(char c = 0; c < 240; c++){ /*320 x 240 file*/
    array[c] = malloc(320);
}
```

That will cause at least 240 pointers of 4 bytes each

Alternatively:

```
array = malloc(320*240);
```

That minimises the pointers, but will cause a multiply for each access during
parsing. Without hardware multiply, that will be expensive in time.

For the parsing, at least three rows is needed at a time in memory.

Reading from SD card is slow, and I am unsure if reading one line at a time and
parsing will be slower than reading the whole file at once, and then parsing.

The answer to this question will determine the memory size requirement of the
processor. Of course, the smaller processor will be cheaper, and that is a huge
factor, but the parsing time is probably an even bigger factor.

Comment: If only 3 rows are needed at a time, can't you just allocate those 3 rows?

Comment: can’t you test this? If you don’t have the processor yet, can’t you borrow just for test? It is very difficult to say which will be faster without actual profiling on the actual hardware.

Comment: At any rate, we can't tell you which is more important for you on this project. There's always a balance between speed and space, and the choices are even more important with embedded. In the end, you'll have to be the once to decide, or find a technique specific to the CPU that could accelerate calculations.

Comment: Are you really sure, that you need a random access to your data? May be you don't need to multiply each time you want to access the data. I mean, for example, if you need to find a summ of each column, then you don't need to multiply, just add 320 and you get the next column element. So it's hard to tell which is the best solution until we don't know what kind of task do you have. And even, if finding the shift of the data in array will take a time, it can be that it isn't so critial as you expect.

Comment: A multiplication by 320 of `x` is trivially strength-reduced to `(x << 6)` + `(x << 8)`. Your compiler likely knows this trick, too. :) That said, I don't believe a single multiplication is going to be the issue here, I/O will very likely be much slower anyway.

Comment: BTW `char c` -> `unsigned char c` and `c < 240` --> `c < row`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a complete recommendation without knowing what the file accessor methods available would be, but you may want to consider using something like fread to read in a chunk of a specified size at a time, then use that to continually populate (as has already been said) a 3-buffer set. So something like:

```
FILE *fileStream = fopen ("file.bin", "rb");
char **array = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 3);
int i = 0;
size_t bytesRead = 0;

while (!feof(fileStream))
{
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        /* If read has returned some bytes - i.e. not at EOF */
        if (fread (&array[i], 1, 320, fileStream))
        {
            /* Assuming target knows size of array. Pass in number in iteration
             * so target function knows where the read ends */
            doProcessing (array, i);
         }
    }
}
```

This will allow the filestream to take care of IO buffering etc which you're concerned about within its own internal buffer, then you can use fread to read a la carte.

However in saying this, I'm making several assumptions:

1. That fread functions are available for accessing this SD card
2. That your "row" based structure is actually sound for the binary file you're parsing and that you don't *also* have to store the number of bytes populated for each row or newline delimited set of data.